# youtube-dl giving 407 Proxy Authorization Required after some minutes

Tags: proxy, youtube-dl

I'm using the following command on a windows terminal:

```
youtube-dl -ciw --proxy myuser:mypass@proxy.abc.com:8080 "https://www.youtube.com/user/CodeNMore/videos"
```

to download a channel/playlist. 
Everything went ok. The first *n* videos are downloaded, but after some minutes youtube-dl give me this error:

```
  ...
    [download] Downloading video 79 of 81
    [youtube] nhGbFcIW7bc: Downloading webpage
    ERROR: Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authorization Required> (caused by URLError(OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authorization Required',),))
    [download] Downloading video 80 of 81
  ...
```

I guess that's because some proxy configuration that makes the connection/socket to expire.

Is there a way to keep up my proxy active and validated until youtube-dl finishes its job?

Comment: If your hypothesis is correct - it makes  sense - then the answer is no,  there isn't.

Comment: The more likely solution to this problem is to simply finish up your downloads before the proxy times out.

Comment: @Anaksunaman Indeed, as long I keep using the internet (i.e. browsing sites, etc) the proxy revalidades and youtube-dl keep working. As soon I got idle the proxy goes out and the 407 messages start popping out... =[

Comment: Well I found an alternative (not a solution) by keeping the proxy busy and working letting my browser accessing a page like [this](https://www.quackit.com/html/html_editors/scratchpad/preview.cfm?example=/javascript/javascript_refresh_page_auto_refresh) that reloads every n seconds... Dirty but works so far...